# Was there a time when OS did not automatically handle garbage collection?

Tags: c, memory-management, operating-system, heap-memory

This is more of a history question rather than a software problem but I as I am currently learning the C language in University alongside an Operating System module (I did not get a straight answer from my lecturer, hence why I came here), I wanted to know if there ever was a time in the start of the OS era, if OS did not handle badly-behaved programs and left dynamically allocated memory reserved even if the program that allocated them had terminated.

Comment: Yes, and it's still common on for example operating systems for embedded systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necessity is mother of invention.
In start, computers were not multi-tasking and were made for specific purposes which is why garbage-collector was not needed but as soon as creating and killing of programs was introduced i.e. multi-tasking in essence, there was immediate need for clearing memory otherwise only 2 things were supposed to happen:

- Memory overflow after a program or programs had been running for sometime.
- Memory overwrite whenever new memory was needed.

Both are not wise solutions and owing to the fact that memories were very small in that era, this problem was quickly identified and hence garbage collector was born.

**Note:**

Garbage-collector is not needed if programs are manually allocating memory locations and are well aware of the size they can use which means they keep over-writing garbage themselves. For example, in embedded systems, we cannot afford to allocate memory to collector too. We would rather program itself properly.

In case of OS though, garbage collector is a must.

Comment: Thank you very much for the speedy answer. This is an excellent starting point to researching further garbage collection understanding, if not the whole case!